# SQL-query for 'version-control' feature

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing something like 'version-control' of the document that is being uploaded. So when I upload a new document, I check if there is already a document with same name in the table, and if there is, I add this record as well, but I add +1, to column 'version'. However, I need to display only the last version of document to the user. My knowledge of SQL is pretty basic, so I can't figure out how to make an query that should select all records with same values in column 'name' but grab only the row with highest value in 'version' column.

Technology is RoR.
Database is SQLite.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: same name  or same content?  something to think about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty basic where select

```
YouModel.where(name: params[:name]).order("version DESC").limit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a gem like `papertrail`. It versions `ActiveRecord` models.

Comment: I don't think there is need, of any additional gem here, I think there are way to do this with a mid-difficulty query.

Comment: @OlegKiviljov: the mid-difficulty query will also turn your schema into a giant mess with performance ramifications where you least expect them, if you end up doing queries like the one highlighted by Ivan.